# I want to do mapreduce row-wise in dataframe python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv, mapreduce

I have a dataframe like this

```
productId         text
0   B00020JQDK  [like, many, here,i, i, missed, 'harsh, realm']
1   B00020JQDK  [chris, carter's, harsh, realm, only, lasted,]
2   B00020JQDK  [it, doesn't, take, long, to,see, see, the, story]
```

and I want output like this

```
productId         text
0   B00020JQDK  [(like,1),(many,1), (here,1), (i,2),(missed,1),('harsh,1),(realm',1)]
1   B00020JQDK  [(chris,1), (carter's,1),(harsh,1),(realm,1),(only,1),(lasted,1)]
2   B00020JQDK  [(it,1),(doesn't,1), (take,1),(long,1),(to,1),(see,2),(the,1),(story,1)]
```

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

While this approach doesn't employ map or reduce, this is one way to accomplish the task.

```
def count_items(lst):
    # Create a dictionary with word counts
    itms_counts = dict()
    out = []
    for itm in lst:
        cnt = itms_counts.pop(itm, 0)
        cnt =+ 1
        itms_counts[itm] = cnt
    for itm in lst:
        # output the item counts in the same order as input
        cnt = itms_counts.pop(itm, None)
        if cnt:
            out.append((itm, cnt))
    return out     

# Update the data frame replacing the text column with the word count tuples
df['text'] = df.apply(lambda row: count_items(row.text), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, but this function splitting the words like, [(s,1),(e,1),(a,2)] how to overcome this? also row 1 data is getting filled in the whole dataframe. If can help me to resolve this then that could be great.

Comment: I don't follow your comment, when I run the above code on my system, it produces the desired output as you described.  Are you saying it produces something different on your system?

Comment: Yes, it's not producing the same output. Instead I'm getting output like [(h,1),(a,1),(p,2),(y,1)]  its counting the letters of the words. Also only first row of the output is written in the whole column.

Comment: Does your text column look exactly like your example?  in other words is it a list of word strings or is it a single string?

Comment: It is actually of a single string, which I converted into a list of words but since that didn't work for me, I used array.

Comment: If you use a list of words, my solution should work for you

Answer (score 0):

I extracted column text from dataframe into an array then used for loop

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

text=pd.DataFrame()
text['text']=df['text']
text.head()

arr = np.array(text)
array1=np.array([])

for i in arr:
  a=str(i).split()
  b =collections.Counter(a)
  print(b)
  array1=np.append(arr=array1,values=b)

df["reduced"]=array1
df.head()
```